# I am trying to get a timestamp (date) when I click a checkbox

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using the function onEdit()

I want the word "Paid" to show up on column "I" and the "date" on column "J" when I click the checked box. I am trying to create something for my husband to use with his contracting business to keep up with payments.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rbMLW0xX1b_mb7jEgByC2em5qMDgYPUkRB-2YtjlWgw/edit#gid=1640457307

Here is the code that I have been trying to get to work. I am so new at this like started yesterday. I am trying to post the code but it is not working for me. I have no idea how to use the "code format" that pops up on the right hand side. I am going to try and put it in the comments.

Comment: function onEdit () {}
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().     
  if ( s.getName("Sheet1"));{ //checks that were on Sheet1 or not}.   
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();    
  var r = s.getActiveCell(); //watches edited cell.   
if(r.getColumn() == 8 ) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column H.   
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);    
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //checks if the adjacent cell is empty or not?    
nextCell.setValue(new Date());    
}
}

Comment: Can't access the file, make sure it is publicly available